# Bitcoin-core how to get all transactions hashes?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, hash, raw-data

Please, can anyone help me how to get all transactions hashes? How to browse all the transactions hashes used in blockchain?

P.S. How simply get a list of all transactions IDs (as a simple text list) if I only have running syncronized bitcoin node on my PC and I do not have any other data such as addresses or something else?

Comment: You can use any block explorer that has an API, but that could take a long time, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The questions aren't very clear, what are you try to do with the hashes or how would you get those hashes (e.g. by public address, TXID, etc.). Please edit to include as much details as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browse BlockChair to find the list of transactions: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions

Then uncheck every box other than TXID (hash):

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions#f=hash

Then use export, and pay them if needed.

Comment: I need the list (hashes) of all transactions used in blockchain. Just list of all hashes that are in Bitcoin blockchain database. I need this for my theoretical research work. I think it is not possible to retrieve them from this site.

Comment: The website says they'd give the data for free for research purposes. What you're looking for is the export button on the right.

Answer (score 0):

> ...how to...?

The answer is: write a program for parsing blockchain. Such program is not too difficult. I've written it from my existed sources in five minutes. The result is here: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GsXh/iLwmeSQ14

Symbol "c" in first column means that this transaction is coinbase

Of course, this file contains only 2k lines, I do not want to dump all transactions into the file. Mail me alistermaclin@mail.ru if you need such program.